# Trying programming with C, Getting Expected x before Y type error

Tags: c, if-statement, compiler-errors

Trying my hand at C (Self teaching and using The New Boston guides) but trying to make a simple ask these questions and then if the answer matches then print X or Y.

I have commented out yourAge as for what I'm doing i dont need it, It works if you remove the if statement and just have the print as Hi, firstName I can see that you're yourAge etc.

The error I'm getting is :

> ||=== Build: Debug in TestProject (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
>   C:\Users\admin-jb\Desktop\TestCProject\TestProject\main.c||In function
>  'main':|
>   C:\Users\admin-jb\Desktop\TestCProject\TestProject\main.c|21|warning: implicit declaration of function 'If' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
>   C:\Users\admin-jb\Desktop\TestCProject\TestProject\main.c|22|error: expected ';' before '{' token|
>   C:\Users\admin-jb\Desktop\TestCProject\TestProject\main.c|33|warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]|
>   ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 2 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Using Code::Blocks 13.12

Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char firstName[20];
//    int  yourAge;
    char excelLike[20];


    printf("Please Enter Your Name?\n");
    scanf("%s", firstName);

//    printf("How old are you?\n");
//    scanf("%d", &yourAge);

    printf("Do you like Excel?\n");
    scanf("%s", excelLike);

    If(strcmp(excelLike, "yes") == 0)
        {
        printf("Hey, %s I love Excel too!!\n", firstName);
        }
    else
        {
        printf("Hey %s, pfft nor do I, its rubbish!\n", firstName);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is `if`, not `If`.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvotes...

Comment: Please do not add the answer into question body, you've already "marked" an answer "accepted", nad that's the way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I wasn't adding another question, I was simply adding a comment to thank people and I was going to leave the question / answer there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C` keywords are *case-sentive*. use `if` instead of `If`.

Related: From `C11` standard, chapter §6.4.1, *Keywords*,

> The above tokens (case sensitive) are reserved (in translation phases 7 and 8) for use as keywords, and shall not be used otherwise.....

As per your usage, compiler is not able to match the keyword `if` with `If` and considering `If` as a function call, which is not defined in your case. Hence you're getting the error message.

That said,

1. The recommended signature for `main()` is `int main(void)`.
2. You should limit the input string length for `scanf()` to avoid possible buffer overflow. You should be using like

   ```
   scanf("%19s", firstName);
   ```
3. Always check the return value of `scanf()` for success.

Answer (score 3):

```
C:\Users\admin-jb\Desktop\TestCProject\TestProject\main.c|21|warning: implicit declaration of function 'If' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
```

You are using `If` instead of `if`. C is case sensitive, meaning you have to be careful with lower- and upper-case letters

Comment: @JamieB You should use an editor with syntax highlighting. It would have colored the `If` differently, like it did in your top post.

Comment: Am not sure where I find this within code::blocks but I'll have a look thank you.